# Obtener un id haciendo uso de las funciones count() y max()

Tags: mysql, sql

No se muy bien que titulo poner para formular esta pregunta asi que toda ayuda para conseguir resolver esta pregunta es bienvenida.

Dadas las siguientes tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El resultado que quiero obtener es el depto_no del departamento con más empleados,** es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He empezado haciendo:

```
SELECT depto_no,count(*) FROM empleado GROUP BY depto_no;
```

Lo cual obtiene lo siguiente y quizá sirva como subconsulta para llegar al resultado que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se como proseguir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
SELECT depto_no,count(*) AS cnt FROM empleado GROUP BY depto_no ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1;
```